# Streaming Webcam in android using yawcam

Tags: android, webcam

i had creating an android apps.
using yawcam that installed on my pc as server to browse webcam feed in my android apps.
but, what i got is, video in actually like in browser, got more white unuse space
this is my code:

public class ViewVideo extends Activity{

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

       //String ipAddress = getIntent().getStringExtra("ipAddress");
       // String portNumber= getIntent().getStringExtra("portNumber");
      SharedPreferences app_preferences1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      String ip = app_preferences1.getString("ip", "null");

      SharedPreferences app_preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      String port = app_preferences2.getString("port", "null");


        WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
        engine.setInitialScale(1);
        engine.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        engine.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        engine.loadUrl("http://"+ip+":"+port);




Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
//Listening to button event
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ViewVideo.this,CameraActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

}
});

what i want to do, is want to view the webcam stream in fullscreen mode without got white space, i know it is because i am using webview() method. 
is there any possible way to view yawcam feed without use webview?
i am so sorry if got any weakness in my question.
thanks in advance